# Get selected values of multiple selects

Tags: jquery

I have a page where the user can generate an undefined amount of `<select>` elements.

e.g.

```
<select>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
    <option>blabla</option>
</select>
```

My question is how can I get the values of all selected options in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an array of selected values:

```
var values = $('select').map(function() {
    return $(this).val(); // or return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: I think the selector should be $('select option:selected')

Comment: @Vishal: No, I want to select the `select` elements, not the `option` elements.

Comment: oops, for some reason I thought it was <select multiple>